# What does "coming apart at the seams" mean?

Tags: idioms

> Meanwhile, Europe’s single currency is coming apart at the seams.

In the example above and in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an idiom. Referring to clothing.

It means that something is falling apart, or declining in quality, as clothing would if it were torn at the seams.

> Seam: A line where two pieces of fabric are sewn together in a garment or other article.

Comment: Did you see the definition of seam MikeVaughan quoted?  A seam is where two pieces of cloth are held together by thread.

Answer (score 4):

> **bursting** (or **bulging**) **at the seams** *informal* (of a place or building) full to overflowing.
>   **come** (or **fall**) **apart at the seams** *informal* (of a person or system) be in a very poor condition and near to collapse : *the attitude of the airport guard was symptomatic of a system falling apart at the seams*.

<sup>*NOAD*</sup>
An earlier version of this second expression was *give way at the seams*, seen in print in its literal sense from the mid 19th century. The first figurative use of the phrase I could find was from *[Across the Campus: A Story of College Life](http://books.google.com/books?id=htkXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA324&dq=%22give%20way%20at%20the%20seams%22&hl=en&ei=Q6DITdnGEsHd0QGuufTiCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&sqi=2&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22give%20way%20at%20the%20seams%22&f=false)* by Caroline Fuller, 1899:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=htkXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA324&dq=%22give+way+at+the+seams%22&hl=en&ei=Q6DITdnGEsHd0QGuufTiCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&sqi=2&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22give%20way%20at%20the%20seams%22&f=false]

The related phrase *bursting at the seams* came first, but all versions of the phrase seem to have followed [similar paths](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=come+apart+at+the+seams%2Ccoming+apart+at+the+seams%2Cgive+way+at+the+seams%2Cgiving+way+at+the+seams%2Cburst+at+the+seams%2Cbursting+at+the+seams%2C+fall+apart+at+the+seams%2C+falling+apart+at+the+seams%2C+bulge+at+the+seams%2C+bulging+at+the+seams&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in their trek from literal to predominantly figurative use:

[image: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=come+apart+at+the+seams%2Ccoming+apart+at+the+seams%2Cgive+way+at+the+seams%2Cgiving+way+at+the+seams%2Cburst+at+the+seams%2Cbursting+at+the+seams%2C+fall+apart+at+the+seams%2C+falling+apart+at+the+seams%2C+bulge+at+the+seams%2C+bulging+at+the+seams&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3]

Answer (score -1):

Also I think that "creaking at the seams" might be from nautical phrasing referring to the tarred seams in ships wooden hulls being under strain. A lot of English idioms come from our rich Naval history.

Comment: Yes, maybe you're right. Can you add some citations to support the assertions made here?